# how to echo the first N files from a directory

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

For a flatfile newslister, i store all the data in `.txt` files
A list of all the .txt files are in the directory `messages`
To get all the titles of newsmessages (2nd line of each txt file) i use a foreach:

```
foreach($pagenewsmsgs as $file){
    // open and prepare newsmessage
    $newsmsg = 'messages/';
    $newsmsg .= $file;
    $fh = fopen($newsmsg, 'r');
    $txtnewsmsg1 = file_get_contents($newsmsg);
    $txtnewsmsg = stripslashes($txtnewsmsg1);                                               
    // get data out of txt file                             
    $lines = file($newsmsg, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);// filedata into an array                                                
    $news_title = $lines[1]; //  news title                                                             
    echo $news_title.'<br />'; // echo all the title from each .txt file

    fclose($fh);

} // end foreach
```

This loops echos me the title of all the .txt files.
How can i echo the title of only the first 5 .txt files?

Comment: Set a counter and exit the loop when it gets to five.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a counter and exit the loop when it gets to five:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($pagenewsmsgs as $file) {
    // do stuff
    $counter++;
    if(5 == $counter) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

perhaps use [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) with a `length` parameter to select the subset of elements you want:

```
foreach(array_slice($pagenewsmsgs, 0, 5) as $file){
    [...]
}
```